# N2CMS: how to add popup conent

Tags: user-interface, popup, editor, modal-dialog, n2cms

I have a news-type website that I am looking to create using N2CMS, but besides the regular operations (being able to see a calendar, viewing lists of news, viewing news details etc.), part of the content in the website is displayed in "modal" popups (similar to the ModalPopupExtender from the AjaxToolkit) inside the page (for example if you click Login, a popup panel appears with the login controls).

My question is: is there a way of adding a handler for a link, and displaying a "modal" popup when the link is clicked? If so, can this be done from the template GUI editor (and how)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N2CMS doesn't have any built-in handlers to create modal pop-ups for links. However, N2CMS does ship with the Jquery JavaScript library. My suggestion would be to use JavaScript in your site template to select and format the desired links with modal dialogs -- but that can't be done from the GUI editor, you'd need to do it in the template code directly.